# How do I set the ASP.NET version for a Virtual Directory using IIS Manager 7.0?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

In the old version of IIS Manager, I could just right-click on a VD, hit properties, and then in the ASP.NET tab pick the version of ASP.NET I wanted to run.  Does anyone know if that is still possible?  I am running a localhost instance of IIS on my Vista box and I am not used to the new UI that IIS 7 comes with.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to change the application pool - the ASP.NET version is set at the application pool level.

Left click the virtual directory in IIS manager, then on the far right of the screen click on 'advanced settings' The application pool is at the top of the list there.

If you need to, you can add a new application pool by right clicking the 'application pools' icon in the left pane and selected 'Add Application Pool'

Answer (score 5):

IIS7 has two options within a "website". In IIS6 you'd add a sub-app as a "Add Virtual Directory..." in IIS7 doing so forces you to keep the same AppPool and thus .NET framework version as the website.

But, IIS7 now has an "Add Application..." options, which allows you to essentially do what IIS6 had allowed, so that you can explicitly state the AppPool to run in and it can differ from the parent website.

Answer (score 2):

In IIS7 the ASP.NET version is specified in an application pool (which is then used by your web app). There's a screenshot of the dialog here:

http://www.stolenbit.com/2008/10/select-aspnet-version-in-iis-7.html